# Dynamically create object tests with intern

Tags: intern

The BDD and TDD styles both seem to easily accommodate dynamically creating tests since each test is a function call.

The object interface, however, doesn't seem to accommodate this very well. It would seem I would have manually build up the object before using it in `registerSuite`.

Is there an easier way of doing this via the object testing interface or should I just use TDD/BDD for dynamic creation of tests?

I think it would be much cleaner for me to use the same testing interface across all tests, so this question will impact which testing interface I proceed with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically create tests with any of the interfaces. With TDD, you might do something like

```
tdd.suite('suite 1', function () {
    tdd.test('test 1', function () { ... });
});
```

With the object interface you can either build up a test object and then register it:

```
var tests = { name: 'suite1' };
tests.test1 = function () { ... };
registerSuite(tests);
```

or call `registerSuite` with a function and build the suite within that:

```
registerSuite(function () {
    function test1() { ... }
    return { name: 'suite1', test1: test1 }
});
```